# Communication security in client-server based iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, encryption

I want to secure the communication between my iPhone client & server. To achieve this as a first step I want my server to respond to only authorized clients. So, even if someone hacks the communication channel he should not be able to create a request which would enable him to get a proper response from server.

My question here is that is there any hashing/encryption-decryption algorithm which is shared between JAVA & Objective C in a sense that if I use a private key to encrypt some security data on iPhone client in objective C using some algorithm it could appropriately be decrypted on my server which is JAVA based & vice-versa.

Any suitable code example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and indeed, most secure) way to ensure confidentiality of communication in iOS is to use HTTPS to talk to your back end. NSURLConnection supports this directly. Developing one's own security protocol is a well-known software development anti-pattern (ie, a design pattern that **shouldn't** be adopted).

It isn't clear from your question whether "authorized clients" refers to applications (ie only an "official" client app can talk to the back end) or users. The latter is definitely better supported, through the authentication support in NSURLConnection. Basically, the user supplies his username and password, and this information is sent to the back end on each request. The user's credentials can be cached in the Keychain.

Authenticating the client app is possible via HTTP client certificates, but is likely to be tricky to implement in a secure manner.

Comment: I am using HTTPS only but to be doubly sure I want to authorize client calls before responding back from server. Additionally, HTTPS/SSL is also vulnerable.

Comment: A *lot* of systems are perfectly fine with basic HTTP authentication, with confidentiality of the data (and credentials) provided by HTTPS. Although all systems are vulnerable to some types of attacks, I think you need a realistic threat assessment... Do you really need that extra protection? How likely are those esoteric threats? Keep in mind that any security protocol of your own design is almost guaranteed to be less secure that the tried and true methods.

Answer (score 1):

A low-stakes way to authenticate the client is with a shared secret.  The client signs it's requests with the secret using an MD5 or SHA1 hash (libraries for both can be had in Java or Objective C).  The server confirms the authenticity of the client by performing the signature on the request in the same manner, then comparing the signature to the one passed by the client.  If they match, then the server trusts the request.

Comment: What if someone hacks the n/w channel & send the same secret key?

Comment: The secret isn't sent with the messages, just the signature generated by the secret.  The server signs the clear part of the message with the same (shared) secret.  If it can generate the same signature, then it trusts the sender.  This is vulnerable to a hack, but the bigger risk comes from a decompile of the client, rather than anything in the transmission.